# javascript - wait for loop to finish first

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to finish first all results before going to another loops. How can I manage to achieve that?

```
function callback_Original(results, status) { 
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                createMarker_Original(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

It always gives few places sometimes.

```
function createMarker_Original(place) {
    var photos = place.photos;
    if (!photos) {
        return;
    }

    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });



    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
          infowindow.setContent('<div style="float:left"><img src="' + photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 120, 'maxHeight': 120}) 
          + '"></div><div style="float:right; padding: 10px;"><b>Name: </b>'+  place.name +'<br/>'+
          '<b>Coordinates : </b>'+ place.geometry.location +'<br/>'+
          '<b>Type: </b>'+ type +'<br/>');
          infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

Comment: What does `createMarker_Original` do?

Comment: Also, JavaScript in the browser is (for the most part) asynchronous - it does not block or wait - so if you're making an external HTTP request then, no, you cannot block or wait for it to finish - you have to structure your program around the concept of asynchronous-programming. It's the future: Node.js is entirely async, C# has `await` and C++ is getting something similar.

Comment: Is there a way to do that? @Dai

Comment: Yes, but we need to see the rest of your program in context.

Comment: Update sir @dai

Comment: Creating markers and adding event listeners are both synchronous operations. The calling function should behave correctly with natural line by line flow. If you get fewer markers than expected, then `results` are incomplete.

Answer (score 6):

What about using Promise?(ES6 Code)

```
function callback_Original(results, status) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        createMarker_Original(results[i]);
                    }
                    resolve();
                }else
                    reject("Places service error");
            });
        }
```

And then just use

```
callback_Original(a,b)
.then(response => {
// Loop finished, what to do nexT?
})
.catch(error => {
// Error
console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: If you accept that `resolve()` would be called when everything in the loop   is complete, then it follows that `createMarker_Original()` is synchronous and the OP's original code would also work as he wants.

Answer (score 1):

use `async`, it'll wait for `promise`. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
function callback_Original_child(results, status) { 
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) { 
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                createMarker_Original(results[i]);
          }
        }
    });
}

async function callback_Original(results, status) { 
    try {
        await callback_Original_child(results, status);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

callback_Original()
```

Comment: I'd updated my answer. for more detail go to reference. I have given.